# After killing the app from the background, app should run gps tracking application in Android

Tags: android, geolocation, android-gps

I am making a GPS tracking application. The app should track the user location. In my case, it tracks when an app is in the background and open. if I am killing my app from the background I am not getting location updates. Other apps like Life360 is able to track the user's location even after killing the app.

This is our code and we still have an issue

```
public class BService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "BService";
    private static Location xLocation;
    private static LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private static GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static FusedLocationProviderApi mFusedLocationProviderApi = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi;
    private static String mLocation = "";
    private Context xContext;

    private LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location lo) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + mLocation);
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand: ");
        xContext = this;
        initGps();
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    private void initGps() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000 * 60);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000 * 40);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(xContext)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                        Location lo = null;
                        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(xContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                            lo = mFusedLocationProviderApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
                        if (lo != null) {
                            Log.i(TAG, "onConnected: " + lo);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                    }
                })
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                    }
                })
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        LocationSettingsRequest mLocationSettingsRequest = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
                .addLocationRequest(mLocationRequest)
                .build();

        LocationServices.SettingsApi.checkLocationSettings(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationSettingsRequest)
                .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<LocationSettingsResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(@NonNull LocationSettingsResult locationSettingsResult) {
                        final Status status = locationSettingsResult.getStatus();
                        switch (status.getStatusCode()) {
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                                Notifier.cancel(xContext);
                                if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(xContext, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                                    mFusedLocationProviderApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, mLocationListener);
                                break;
                            case LocationSettingsStatusCodes.RESOLUTION_REQUIRED:
                                // Gps Disabled
                                Notifier.notify(xContext, "You've turned off location services, which has disabled Beep." +
                                        " Turn location services on to reconnect.");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

}
```

The issue we are having is the onservice method is working but the code inside is not responding. The services are not responding when the app is killed.In custom OS Android

Comment: Can you share code you are using to track location of the user?

Comment: @Chirag Why do you want to track user's location when he is not using your app?

Comment: Use a `Service`.

Comment: @Jack Let me explain my use case here. My app is an SOS and Location tracking app. I add my family member and they add me to the app, once we have added each other, we can see our locations on the map. When I the app is in foreground or background I am able to see the location update, but once i kill the app, i am not able to get an updated location.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen - what service?

Comment: @ChiragJagtiani You can use Intent Service

Comment: @Jack so we tried your solution and in other versions of Android, it worked but failed on Nougat. any other suggestions for Android 7 and above?

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen - i have updated the thread with my code. Please have a look and let me know if you come accross anything.

Comment: @Jack I have updated the thread with my code. Please have a look and let me know if you come across anything